# Can't get preg_match to return the data needed

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Ok so lets say I need to take a part this link: `http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xnstwx_bmw-eco-pro-race_auto`

I need to get

`[0] => xnstwx`

`[1] => bmw-eco-pro-race_auto`

and I am trying it with: `preg_match('/video\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)_/i', $video['url'], $match);`

and I get:

`[0] => video/xnstwx_`

`[1] => xnstwx`

than I try it with: `preg_match('/video\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)_/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)', $video['url'], $match);`
and I guess you already know that is wrong.

I have always ran away of regex for no reason and now I am trying to learn using a regular-expression cheat sheet but now I am a bit stuck :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('@video/([^_]+)_(.+)@', $video['url'], $match);
```

And a tip: it's always a good idea not to use `/` as the regex delimiter when dealing with urls, so you won't have to escape all the slashes in your pattern.

Answer (score 2):

A bit late, but:

```
<?php
$u = 'http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xnstwx_bmw-eco-pro-race_auto';
preg_match('/([A-Za-z0-9]+)_([A-Za-z0-9].+)/', $u,$m);
print_r($m);
?>
```

gives:

```
Array ( [0] => xnstwx_bmw-eco-pro-race_auto [1] => xnstwx [2] => bmw-eco-pro-race_auto )
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `(.+)` after the `_`.  This traps one or more of any character, grouped by `()` following the `_`.

```
preg_match('/video\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)_(.+)/i', $video['url'], $match);

var_dump($match);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(34) "video/xnstwx_bmw-eco-pro-race_auto"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "xnstwx"
  [2]=>
  string(21) "bmw-eco-pro-race_auto"
}
```

There are many potential ways to do this, but this is just the first example that came to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to get your matches in $match[1] and $match[2].

```
preg_match("/.*\/video\/([a-z0-9]+)_(.*)$/i", $video['url'], $match);
```

no need for A-Z with the i modifier, the first element in the array is always the fully matched expression, which is why the expected results are in position 1 and 2.

Regards,
Phil,

EDIT: didn't realise I had to use code tags for the escaped slashes to show up!